# aws inspector vs Nessus which one to chose for aws cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, inspector, nessus

So we want to setup a security scanners for a mixed environment of Linux & windows instances on AWS so i came across Inspector and Nessus so i just want to get little more clearity and experts advice on which one to chose

thanks!!